# Parallel processing values emitted by flow in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow, coroutinescope

Kotlin code

```
runBlocking {
    flow {
        for (i in 0..4) {
            println("Emit $i")
            emit(i)
        }}  .onEach { if (it%2 == 0) delay(200) // Block 1
                println("A: got $it")
            }
            .onEach { println("B: got $it") } // Block 2
            .collect()
}
```

print in console:

```
Emit 0
A: got 0
B: got 0
Emit 1
A: got 1
B: got 1
Emit 2
...
```

How can I run parallel process both block1 & block2 to get messages from block 2 before block 1 in half cases?

Comment: You may be interested in this ongoing discussion: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1147

Answer (score 1):

You could try to launch separate coroutines in those blocks:

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())

flow {
    for (i in 0..4) {
        println("Emit $i")
        emit(i)
    }
}.onEach { // Block 1
    scope.launch {
        if (it % 2 == 0) delay(200) 
        println("A: got $it")
    }

}.onEach { // Block 2
    scope.launch { 
        println("B: got $it") 
    }
}.launchIn(scope)
```

In this case `Block 2` will be printed before `Block 1`. `SupervisorJob` needs here to prevent cancelling launched coroutines when one of them fails.

This solution doesn't guarantee the order, e.g. there can be logs in the next order:

```
Emit 0
Emit 1
Emit 2
Emit 3
Emit 4

B: got 0
A: got 1
B: got 1
B: got 2
A: got 3
B: got 3
B: got 4
A: got 0
A: got 2
A: got 4
```

---

We can also use `callbackFlow` if we need to handle result:

```
scope.launch {
    parallelIntFlow().collect {
        println("$it")
    }
} 

fun intFlow() = flow {
    for (i in 0..4) {
        println("Emit $i")
        emit(i)
    }
}

fun parallelIntFlow() = callbackFlow {
    // parallel processing of ints
    val job = intFlow()
        .onEach {
            launch {
                if (it % 2 == 0) delay(200)
                send("A: got $it")
            }
        }
        .onEach {
            launch {
                send("B: got $it")
            }
        }
        .launchIn(this)
    awaitClose {
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```